# Make Jenkins metadata available for projects

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I've set up a Jenkins server + the Metadata plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Metadata+plugin).

I'm having trouble understanding how this metadata can be used in projects. I've added some keys with default values (e.g. `SOME_METADATA_KEY`, default value `FOO` as string) using the `Jenkins -> MetadataConfiguration` page. `Expose to environment` is also checked.

Now, if I create a new project, in the "Meta Data" section I can see `SOME_METADATA_KEY` as a **preset value**.

How can I use it ? I want it to end up in my build environment; just running a shell script with `env` doesn't show the variable.

In the project, I've tried:

- created a new string value with the same name as the predefined variable, no value set (I was hoping to get the predefined value as a default) --> FAIL, variable not set at all.
- create a new string value with a different name (i.e. `SOME_FOOBAR_KEY`) and a value of `$SOME_METADATA_KEY` --> FAIL, variable has value of "$SOME_METADATA_KEY" instead of `FOO`

My goal is to be able to define "global" values in a single place and have them available for multiple projects as evironment variables.

Comment: According to the Metadata plugin page, the environment variable will have the prefix `MD_`. Did you check for `MD_SOME_METADATA_KEY`?

Comment: Yes, I printed everything using `env`, nothing's there; unless, of course, I define the value inside the project itself (in that case it works); but I want to use the preset values somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Metadata is weird. If you're expecting to use it like a global environment variable, it's not going to behave the way you want.

From the [Metadata plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Metadata+plugin):

> We differentiate between MetadataDefinitions and MetadataValues. The idea comes from the parameter setup in Jenkins.
>   A MetadataValue is what's set on the configuration page of a project or slave and is also what is saved for a build.
>
> MetadataDefinitions are used by admins for making sure that certain metadata exist on all projects.
>   A MetadataDefinition is set up through a special configuration page, configuring a name and default value for the definition.
>   Once set, the MetadataDefinition will end up in all projects on the server, prompting the user to set a value for it when the project is configured.
>   MetadataDefinitions are then converted to MetadataValues.

As I understand it, you currently have a Metadata Definition (from the global metadata configuration) and you need to change it to a Metadata Value so it's available in your project.

The rules for how Definitions are converted into Values are not well explained. In my experience, editing the project's configuration and selecting or editing the specific preset value seems to import the Definition into the project as a Value. So, if you follow these steps, you can see your metadata in the project's build environment:

1. Define a key (`MY_KEY`) and value in the global Metadata Configuration, make sure *Expose to Environment* is checked.
2. Edit the project's configuration. The metadata key and default value should appear under presets. Select or edit the value of the preset that you want to "import" into the project. Save.
3. Run a build and check the environment for `MD_MY_KEY`.

Based on all of this, I'd be concerned about trying to use the value in a global Definition across many projects. I suspect the project's Value may be divorced from the global Definition value when the project converts the Definition to a Value. The Metadata documentation implies that Definitions are for making sure metadata exists on projects, not necessarily for managing the same values across projects.

Comment: Indeed the metadata plugin is weird. I'm not sure what you mean on step 2 to select; yeah, I see the preset variable "MY_KEY" with its default value in my project's configuration, and I can edit the value. But with the default value or not, the variable is not available in my environment, either as `MY_KEY` or `MD_MY_KEY` (just running "env" as shell script build step to test)

Comment: @Unknown Interesting, the behavior you describe does not match mine. In the project configuration if I select (click in the present value field) the value or edit the value, the variable shows up in the environment. Jenkins 1.565.1 LTS, Metadata 1.1.0b.

Comment: I'm on 1.585 with 1.1.0b. I'll try to grab your version of Jenkins and try.

Comment: No idea what I'm doing different here. Can you spot any issue in my configuration? http://imgur.com/a/DiMxC

Answer (score 0):

I think figured this out, eventually. You need to go to `Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties`,  check `Metadata` and add the values there, check `Expose to environment`.

I have no clue how `Metadata Configuration` is related, that one is either broken or extremely counterintuitive :(

**Later edit:** Ok, I was wrong. It doesn't work. But I figured out a way to achieve what I want, `Jenkins -> Configure System -> Global properties -> Environment Variables`, set everything there.